# Playing beep in C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, beep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beep on Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072909/beep-on-linux-in-c)

I have been looking for a way to play a simple beep in Linux, but all what I found don't work.

I've tried the \a, \b \7 but anyone play the beep.

I would like to play it without the use of sound libraries, later I will change the beep for a  real sound using any library, but right now I'm only interested in play a beep for testing purposes

As I said, I'm using Linux (exactly LMDE) so the easiest way of Windows (include windows.h and Beep()) can't be used.

So how could I implement this? A system call or something like that.

EDIT: I ended doing it in Java and I have it working already.

Comment: Are you sure your beep works in the console you're using ? Nowadays it generally flashes the console window, or -better yet- do nothing at all.

Comment: Now that you said it, I just enabled the alert sound and tried for example backspace without nothing to delete, and it doesn't play the beep either.

Comment: toot is a cross-platform C file that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep. http://github.com/vareille/toot

Answer (score 4):

Try including ncurses.h

```
#include <ncurses.h>

beep();
```

compile with the -lncurses flag

Reference : http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_beep.3x.html

Also this question : [make sounds (beep) with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c)

**Edit**:

try this command line

> sudo sh -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/console"

Also try the code given at http://www.linuxplayer.org/2010/04/beep-your-pc-speaker-in-linux

```
int ms = 5000;
int freq = 440;
ioctl(fd, KDMKTONE, (ms<<16 | 1193180/freq));
```

Comment: Nothing.. no way. But the beep itself works because in a terminal I run "beep" and it sounds.

Comment: @Elemenophee i have added few more solutions after edit.. please try them too.

Comment: Thanks for help but as I said in the edit, I switched to Java and did it using the sound libraries already, so I skipped the step of use beep for testing.

Comment: the last link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo -e "\a"`?   
 
You might also try:  `echo -ne '\007'`

Also there is a `beep` command-line tool that you should be able to install using your distributions package management system.

It should cause the terminal to emit a beep.  
I've tested it on a few Linux distributions and seems to work correctly.

Comment: You might want to check your sounds configuration and make sure you have a notification sounds configured.

Comment: Are you doing this in a shell terminal?