# Making sound with different frequencies

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

Is there a function in X11 or built into Linux that can produce a Beep sound with different frequencies?

Some function like the `Beep(dwFreq, dwDuration)` function in Windows which has arguments that allows for the specification of frequency in hertz and a duration in milliseconds.

Comment: You may want to start with [xbell(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xbell) then look at [xdevicebell(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xdevicebell) then look at [xchangefeedbackcontrol(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xchangefeedbackcontrol) however it may be a bit complicated.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072909/beep-on-linux-in-c

Comment: This is actually a good question and I would be interested in an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try with *speaker-test(1)*.
It can be usually found on **alsa-utils** package.

example (generates a sine wave, 440 Hz):

```
speaker-test -f 440 -t sine
```

Comment: How can I adjust time?

Comment: Check `man speaker-test`. Maybe you can find one option that helps.

Comment: I tested options but it always produces a 10 sec Beep.

Comment: Well, if you can't find a solution you can always go with `speaker-test -f 440 -t sine & ; sleep 2 ; killall speaker-test` for 2 seconds. Depending on your implementation of sleep you can use any floating point number. But this is nasty.