# How to make a beep sound in C language for Linux

Tags: c

There are other questions on how to make a beep sound in C(using a function) for Windows and Mac OS, but I could find none for Linux (the one I need), do I need to "#include..." anything into my code before using the fucntion?

Comment: You could try `putchar('\07');`

Comment: ... what could be written as `putchar('\a');` with a = alarm, see ["Bell character"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) -- No, you don't need any extra include.

Comment: http://www.johnath.com/beep/beep.c

Also: this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072909/beep-on-linux-in-c